# How to use bip39 module in angular?

Tags: wallets, ethereumjs, angular2, bip39

I am trying to create an ethereum wallet app using Ionic. I have tried to import bip39 node module directly in the angular project but it gives me error. Please help

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as bip39 from 'bip39';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EthereumService {
  mnemonic = 'hello world';
  constructor() {
    this.mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic();
  }
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at inherits (inherits_browser.js:5)
    at Object../node_modules/hash-base/index.js (index.js:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Object../node_modules/md5.js/index.js (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Object../node_modules/create-hash/browser.js (browser.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Object../node_modules/bip39/src/index.js (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/app/ethereum.service.ts (signup.page.ts:15)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import Bip39 from 'bip39';
```

https://github.com/mottolini/ionic-ethereum/blob/master/src/providers/ethereum/ethereum.ts

Verify you code!